# Return custom objects Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have dificulties figuring how a function can return an object in Excel VBA.

For example, in Java, I am used to write it like this:

```
Private ArrayList<> getARandomArrayList() {
    //... My code
    return anArrayList;
}
```

This method should return an arrayList that I can use.

If I do this in Excel, I believe it is supposed to look like this:

```
Function getARandomArrayList() As System.Collections.ArrayList
    '... My code
    getARandomArrayList = anArrayList
End Function
```

When I try to use this kind of function, I get a "Compile error: User-defined type not defined" error window. If I use variables type like Double or String, I have no problem. It is only with objects that I get errors.

Comment: You have to set a reference to the relevant object library in order to be able to declare a variable as a type contained in it.

Comment: Thanks it finally worked. I'll quote you in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `VBA.Collection` may work for you, depending on your needs. (Edit: And as Vincent points out in the comments, no additional references are required.) Here's what it'd look like to use one:

```
Function getSomeCollection() As VBA.Collection
    'Declare a collection
    Dim newCollection As VBA.Collection

    'Initialize the collection
    Set newCollection = New VBA.Collection

    'Add a string. 
    'Other methods are Item (access by index), Count, and Remove (by index)
    newCollection.Add "hello"

    'Reference the collection (note it's 1-based)
    MsgBox newCollection(1)

    'Set the return value
    Set getSomeCollection = newCollection
End Function
```

Comment: Very interesting! I will probably use it instead of ArrayList.

Comment: In fact, it is a double answer since I don't need to select references.

Comment: Updated answer to mention that it doesn't require additional references. (Btw, if this answer helped, please mark as answer and/or upvote! Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

As Rory said:

> You have to set a reference to the relevant object library in order to be able to declare a variable as a type contained in it

I went in reference and activated System librairies.